# How to recover deleted files from Iphone 4(iOS 4.3)

Tags: iphone, windows

I hate itunes and so I usually use Windows7 to browse my Iphone4 and backup Videos and Photos. Yesterday I did just that.

I cut the videos and pasted on the D: drive. It ran out of space so I freed up some space and did cut and paste again. The result was 15 corrupted files and no files on the iphone.

I did this millions of times and it was always ok.

I've looked for recovering software but none seem to recognize the iphone.
I went to an apple store and the dude obviously told me that the proper way to backup files is using itunes. He also mentioned that "there are some products out there that could do that for you. You should google it".

Does anyone know an app that can recover deleted files from an Iphone?

Answer (score 1):

Deleted files? No. He's probably talking about things like [Music Rescue](http://www.kennettnet.co.uk/products/musicrescue/), but they dont recover deleted files unfortunately, just take them off the phone without using iTunes.

Your method of moving photos and movies is fine as you are only accessing the "camera" section of the iPhone's storage, and it is one of the methods that are supported.

I think while you moved files around your cache may have filled up or something happened to the copy paste while they were cut, unfortunately cut is a destroying action, and if you cant ctrl-z immediately, I would assume it's game over.